# JMeter Post request - JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb0

Tags: java, json, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am sending a post request with JSON as a body using JMeter.

I am getting Success response When I executed the same request using postman.

But using JMeter I am getting "JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb0".

Based on the similar questions asked, It seems -(hyphen) causing problems but not 100% sure about that.

These are the Combination of headers I tried:

### First

> Content-type : application/json ;  charset=utf-8

### Second

> Content-type : application/json
>
> Content-Encoding : utf-8

### Below is JSON Body

```
{
   "note":"Test item note",
   "externalIds":[
      {
         "sourceId":"external-0",
         "value":"0003869",
         "type":{
            "key":"33501",
            "value":"Item #",
            "id":3686074
         },
         "_operation":0
      }
   ],
   "description":"TEST 16700654 ROTIS FC 2/5 LB",
   "country":"USA",
   "specialConditions":{
      "isHazmat":true,
      "isOdorSensitive":true
   },
   "status":{
      "code":{
         "id":538663,
         "key":"35001",
         "value":"active"
      }
   },
   "catchWeightType":{
      "id":538674,
      "key":"35051",
      "value":"Inbound"
   },
   "weights":[
      {
         "sourceId":"weights-0",
         "value":10,
         "type":{
            "key":"35301",
            "value":"Net Weight",
            "id":538701
         },
         "unit":{
            "key":"1520",
            "value":"lb"
         },
         "_operation":0
      }
   ],
   "packages":[
      {
         "sourceId":"package-0",
         "maxStackCount":25,
         "nmfc":"123",
         "nmfcSub":"chk87",
         "freightClass":{
            "id":100218,
            "value":"50",
            "key":"5100"
         },
         "value":{
            "value":100.5,
            "currency":{
               "id":100065,
               "value":"USD",
               "key":"1550"
            }
         },
         "temperature":{
            "unit":{
               "key":"1510",
               "value":"°F",
               "id":100058
            },
            "max":78,
            "min":-29.6
         },
         "weights":[
            {
               "unit":{
                  "key":"1520",
                  "value":"lb",
                  "id":100060
               },
               "value":100,
               "type":{
                  "key":"35303",
                  "value":"Tare Weight",
                  "id":538703
               },
               "sourceId":"weight-0",
               "_operation":0
            },
            {
               "unit":{
                  "key":"1520",
                  "value":"lb",
                  "id":100060
               },
               "value":298.7,
               "type":{
                  "key":"35301",
                  "value":"Net Weight",
                  "id":538701
               },
               "sourceId":"weight-1",
               "_operation":0
            }
         ],
         "packageUnit":{
            "key":"6022",
            "value":"cases",
            "id":114043
         },
         "isBaseUnit":true,
         "units":{
            "key":"1530",
            "value":"in",
            "id":100062
         },
         "height":8.813,
         "length":14.938,
         "width":9.438,
         "isStackable":true,
         "ti":13,
         "high":7,
         "_operation":0
      }
   ],
   "customId":"0006686",
   "is_odor_sensitive":true,
   "name":"TEST 16700654 ROTIS FC 2/5 LB",
   "location":{
      "id":632804
   },
   "shelfLife":{
      "value":365,
      "type":{
         "key":"35351",
         "value":"days",
         "id":538705
      }
   },
   "category":{
      "key":"22300",
      "value":"Other",
      "id":139708
   },
   "customer":{
      "id":476093
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a space or special character added. The following should work:

1. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) under HTTP Request
2. Add in Name column: `Content-Type`
3. Add in Value column: `application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @Shyamk327 it just the text wrong encoding, one solution is open JSON with Notepad++ and Choose Encoding  -> Encoding in UTF-8" and then paste to JMeter

Comment: @Shyamk327 any luck in solving this error? I tried to add the content type as suggested in earlier comment. I'm still facing same error. Any leads on how the issue was solved?